# Multiple instances on Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get 2 instances of google charts but only the last one is appearing.

Here is the code:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "charts/getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});

    }


    //Chart 2

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "charts/getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
      chart2.draw(data2, {width: 400, height: 240});

    }
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: is drawChart() your own function? then rename the second one to drawChart2() or something and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']}); only once. I would suggest having an initialize function that would regroup all your drawchart() functions. See below. Apart from that your code looks fine and should work.

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

function initialize() { 
  drawChart();
  drawChart2();
}


function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "charts/getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});

}



function drawChart2() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "charts/getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
  chart2.draw(data2, {width: 400, height: 240});

}
```